# to print smallest and biggest no in an array ( java )

Tags: java, arrays

/* i took two variables with initial values of array so that we have something to compare with for biggest and smallest no. then a loop to check each number of array with the default one for bigger and smaller and if not then will be replaced but why is my answer coming wrong ? */

```
class twod {

    public static void main(String ...NR){

        int a[][] = {{11,21,31},{9,22,23}};
        int maximum = a[0][0];  
        int minimum = a[0][0];

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){    

           for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
                if(a[i][j]>maximum){
                     maximum = a[i][j];
                }
                else if(a[i][j]<minimum){
                     minimum = a[i][j];
                }
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Largest no is  " + maximum); 
        System.out.println("Smallest no is  " + minimum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use some print statements inside your loops to look at what the variables are at any given point and you should see what is going wrong.

Comment: You should try counting how many times you actually enter the inner for loop.

Comment: the print will be something like: `intL@193747` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop only loops `j` through the valid values of `i` (`j<a.length`), which is 0-1, not 0-2.

Loop through the valid index values of the `a[i]` array, not the valid index values of the `a` array.  Change

```
for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
```

to

```
for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
```

Comment: ohh got it, well that ways it can also be done as 

for(int j=0;j<=a.length;j++) ..... 

well i am seeing statement like this for the first time " j<a[i].length "
so if length is 2 and i = 1 what does this statement imply ?

Comment: If `i` is `1`, then `a[i]` refers to {9, 22, 23}, and `a[i].length` is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

In You code `for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)` here `a.length = 2`. So it's not checking for next numbers.

Change it to `for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)` then it will work.